# Designing a DFA and the reverse of it

Tags: regular-languages, automata

There is a theorem that says if a language is regular, its reverse is regular as well. How can I draw a DFA that shows if a language is regular, it's regular as well?

Comment: I'm assuming by reverse, you mean its complement. Just change every accepting state in a DFA to rejecting, and every rejecting to accepting.

Comment: What do you mean by *a DFA which does all the things itself*?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

$L^R$ is the reverse of the language $L$ and for designing $L^R$ you must:

1. Reverse all edges in the transition diagram.
2. The accepting state for the LR automaton is the start state for the main automaton.
3. Create a new start state for the new automaton with epsilon transitions to reach of the accept states for the main automaton.
4. Convert this NFA back into a DFA.

Answer (score -1):

To write the reverse of a DFA, Change all the initial states to final and the final ones to initials(for the later, if there are multiple final states, use a new state and use null transitions to each of them). At last... Reverse the edges.

Comment: There's a catch to reversing the edges at least mentioned in the accepted answer. Speaking of which: Does your answer add anything to it?